# Why do i get the error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first"?

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to play the sound of the apposite color when I open the page. The problem is that it appears this error about the sound and I don't know why.. Especially because all the rest of the code is working just fine. Any suggest please ?

This is the code:

```
var gamePattern = []
var buttonCoulors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]

nextSequence()


function nextSequence() {

  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
  var randomChosenColour = buttonCoulors[randomNumber]
  var randomSound = "sounds/" + randomChosenColour + ".mp3"
  var Sound = new Audio(randomSound)
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour)
  $("#" + randomChosenColour).addClass("pressed")
setTimeout(function(){
$("#"+randomChosenColour).removeClass("pressed")
},100)
Sound.play()

}
```

Comment: By default, Chrome blocks pages from playing audio before the user interacts with the page. Imagine visiting a malicious webpage that opens popups and those popups playing noisy sounds. Is this something good?

Comment: Yeah you are right, so the only way is to make an event where the user can interact to ?

Comment: Yes, prompt the user to interact with the page first.